# snprintf() overflows specified length

Tags: c, printf

I was writing my own ncurses library and suddenly I found in GDB that snprintf() returned length larger than I specified. Is this defined behaviour or some mistake of mine ? The (reproducible) snippet code is this:

```
niko: snippets $ cat snprintf.c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *example_string="This is a very long label. It was created to test alignment functions of VERTICAL and HORIZONTAL layout";

void snprintf_test(void) {
    char tmp[72];
    char fmt[32];
    int len;
    unsigned short  x=20,y=30;

    snprintf(fmt,sizeof(fmt),"\033[%%d;%%dH\033[0m\033[48;5;%%dm%%%ds",48); 
    len=snprintf(tmp,sizeof(tmp),fmt,y,x,0,example_string);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO,tmp,len);
}


int main(void) {
    snprintf_test();
}
niko: snippets $
```

Now we compile with debugging info and run:

```
niko: snippets $ gcc -g -o snprintf snprintf.c
niko: snippets $ gdb ./snprintf -ex "break snprintf_test" -ex run
.....
Reading symbols from ./snprintf...done.
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40058e: file snprintf.c, line 10.
Starting program: /home/deptrack/depserv/snippets/snprintf 

Breakpoint 1, snprintf_test () at snprintf.c:10
10      unsigned short  x=20,y=30;
Missing separate debuginfos, use: dnf debuginfo-install glibc-2.22-16.fc23.x86_64
(gdb) s
12      snprintf(fmt,sizeof(fmt),"\033[%%d;%%dH\033[0m\033[48;5;%%dm%%%ds",48); 
(gdb) print sizeof(fmt)
$1 = 32
(gdb) print sizeof(tmp)
$2 = 72
(gdb) s
13      len=snprintf(tmp,sizeof(tmp),fmt,y,x,0,example_string);
(gdb) print fmt
$3 = "\033[%d;%dH\033[0m\033[48;5;%dm%48s\000\000\000\000\000"
(gdb) print example_string
$4 = 0x4006c0 "This is a very long label. It was created to test alignment functions of VERTICAL and HORIZONTAL layout"
(gdb) s
14      write(STDOUT_FILENO,tmp,len);
(gdb) print len
$5 = 124
(gdb) print sizeof(tmp)
$6 = 72
(gdb)
```

The program outputs garbage at the end of the string. As you can see, the `len` variable returned from snprintf() is indicating that function has printed more than the allowed size of 72. Is this a bug or my mistake? If this behaviour is defined, then why snprintf() docs say it will print at most `n` characters. Very misleading and bug prone statement. I will have to write my own snprintf() to solve this problem.

Comment: `snprintf()` doesn't return the number of characters it wrote, necessarily -- it returns the number it *would* write if it had enough room to print out the entire formatted string.  The return value can be used to figure out how much bigger to make your buffer if it wasn't large enough on the first try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually (from "man snprintf"):

> If the output  was
>          truncated  due  to  this  limit  then the return value is the number of
>          characters (excluding the terminating null byte) which **would have  been
>          written**  to the final string **if enough space had been available**.

Comment: Atleast in GCC 6.8, it the return value includes the NULL character and the stored value is NULL terminated.